# regex python. this code cannot read 2nd line which have username as "-" only

Tags: python, regex, verbose

I am trying to get a dictionary of different keys as follows. the problem is that this code skip the 2nd line which has a username of a different type .i.e user name = -
also the last line I see there are initially space in front of host
can you please help to understand the issue?

```
import re
def logs():
    logdata = """146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
    159.253.153.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700] "POST /e-business HTTP/1.0" 504 19845
    197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554"""
```

---

```
# YOUR CODE HERE
pattern="""  
(?P<host>.*)
(\ -\ )
(?P<user_name>\w.*)
(\ \[)
(?P<time>.*)
(\]\ \")
(?P<request>\w.*)
(\")    
"""


for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only looking for usernames comprising of words, but '-' isn't a word.

If you change the regex to:

```
pattern="""  
(?P<host>.*)
(\ -\ )
(?P<user_name>(\w.*|-))
(\ \[)
(?P<time>.*)
(\]\ \")
(?P<request>\w.*)
(\")    
"""
```

You'll look for either words or '-'

Answer (score 0):

You might make the pattern a bit more specific without using `.*` which will first match until the end of the line, and can then backtrack to fit the next parts of the pattern to get an overall match.

As the format of the logs seems the same, you could match the host and username matching 1+ non whitspace chars using `\S+` as there seem not to be any spaces.

Of course you could also make the parts more specific to match an ip number for the host and a time like pattern for the time.

```
(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) \[(?P<time>[^][]*)] "(?P<request>\w[^"]*)"
```

In parts the pattern matches:

- `(?P<host>\S+)` Group `host`, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `-`  Match literally
- `(?P<user_name>\S+)`  Group `user_name` match 1+ non whitespace chars and a space
- `\[(?P<time>[^][]*)]`  Group `time` match all between square brackets
- `"(?P<request>\w[^"]*)"` Group `request` match all between double quotes

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5h6COe/1)

For example without the `re.VERBOSE` flag

```
import re

def logs():
    logdata = """146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
    159.253.153.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700] "POST /e-business HTTP/1.0" 504 19845
    197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554"""
    pattern = '(?P<host>\S+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) \[(?P<time>[^][]*)] "(?P<request>\w[^"]*)"'

    for item in re.finditer(pattern, logdata):
        print(item.groupdict())
logs()
```

Output

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
{'host': '159.253.153.40', 'user_name': '-', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700', 'request': 'POST /e-business HTTP/1.0'} 
{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}
```